# Best practises with managing DbContext with Ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ninject, dbcontext

I have my own model with mapped entities from Entity wizard:

```
public partial class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext()
        : base("name=MyDbContext")
    {
    }
}
```

And I want inject my context to my repository class. At first I have:

```
public class MyRepository : BaseRepository<Product>, IMyRepository 
    {
        public MyRepository (DbContext _dbContext)
            : base(_dbContext)
        {
        }
}
```

In RegisterServies in NinjectWebCommon I have:

```
kernel.Bind<DbContext>().To<MyDbContext>().InRequestScope();
```

and if I wanted to use my entity, I have to write for example:

```
_dbContext.Set<Product>()
```

But when I search in Google, I always see different approach. DbContext is not binded there, but MyDbContext like:

```
 kernel.Bind<MyDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
```

and injected like:

```
public class MyRepository : BaseRepository<Product>, IMyRepository 
        {
            public MyRepository (MyDbContext _dbContext)
                : base(_dbContext)
            {
            }
    }
```

Then I can simple do (without Set<>):

```
_dbContext.Product()
```

Could you tell me what is the difference between these two types of binding?  What is better apporach?

EDIT:
I noticed that when I delete every binding to MyDbContext (in my second example: `kernel.Bind<MyDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope()`), my database operation still works (reading data etc). For me it is very strange. Why this is happening?

So I have:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        // DBContexts
       //kernel.Bind<DbContext>().To<MyDbContext>().InRequestScope();
       //kernel.Bind<MyDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
    }
```

and with commented bindings my constructor injection still works.

Comment: Look at my answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31027733/ninject-entity-object-cannot-be-referenced-by-multiple-instances-of-ientitychan/31028094#31028094)

Comment: @Callum Linington How it could be helpful to my question?

Comment: it's a best practise IMHO of using the db context

Comment: @Callum Linington This is still not answer on my question. Im using dependency injection for iniect DbContext, but I asked which of my approaches is better and why , when I deleted every binding, DbContext still works properly.

Comment: Well, I assume that is why I put it as a comment, rather than an answer...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot use LINQ joins without strongly typed DbContext (with DbSet properties). So I would go with second approach, which is much cleaner to me.

Comment: But could you explain, why, when I delete binding, MyDBContext still works? (I wrote more in my Edit post).

Comment: @user3146344 Please update question with full binding code.

Comment: I updated my post. As you can see, I commented evvery DBContext binding, and my code, which I added in my post, still works.

Comment: @user3146344, as far as I remember, NInject can resolve concrete class dependencies automatically. So if you are requesting `MyDbContext`, it will create it for you with use of `Activator.CreateInstance`. (That won't work, if you request some interface or abstract class).

Comment: @Vladislav but in what context then? If automatically, so in reqest scope? singleton scope?

Comment: @user3146344, TransientScope (new instance for every request) seems the most reasonable, cause it's used by default and imitates constructor invocation. 
Cannot google it easily, so tried  Ninject 3.2.2.0. and instance of nonregistered class was actually resolved in transient scope. (Of course, parameterless constructor is required for such a behaviour)

Answer (score 0):

Your `DbContext` consumers are expecting a concrete one (which can operate on `Product` class, for example, i.e has a property of type `DbSet<Product>`), so you should specify this in your api. Otherwise it will be legal to provide another context to your repository and it will fail at runtime, while trying to get some `DbSet`.

If you can eliminate possible runtime errors with help of compiler, you should.