# Using Nininject MVC with class libraries

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject, ioc-container

I'm quite new to IoC frameworks so please excuse the terminology.

So what I have is a MVC project with the Nininject MVC references.
I have other class libarys in my project e.g. Domain layer, I would like to be able to use the Ninject framework in there but all of my bindings are in the `NinjectWebCommon.cs` under the `App_Start` folder in the MVC project:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<IHardwareService>().To<WindowsHardwareService>();
    kernel.Bind<IStatusApi>().To<StatusApiController>();
}
```

Currently in my class library I am using constructor injection but sometime I am having to hardcode the dependencies:

```
var service = new WindowsHardwareService();
```

When I would like to be able to do the following:

```
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(.....);
var context = kernel.Get<IHardwareService>();
```

I have not been doing the following because I do not have any modules? 
All of the documentation I have read is mainly aimed at the regular Ninject library and not the MVC version.

What do I need to do, and how can I use the regular Ninject library with the MVC version?

**Update**

This is what I have tried:

The aim of this is so that each project can load the module and get the current injected interface.

**App_Start/NinjectWebCommon.cs** (In MVC Project)

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    var modules = new IoCModules();
    var newKernal = modules.GetKernel();

    kernel = newKernal;
}
```

**IoCModules.cs** (In Project.Ioc project)

```
public class IoCModules
{
    public IKernel GetKernel()
    {
        var modules = new CoreModule();
        return modules.Kernel;
    }
}
```

**CoreModule.cs** (In Project.IoC.Modules project) <-- This is where all the references to all projects are, this get's around any circular dependency issues.

```
public class CoreModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
       Bind<IHardwareService>().To<WindowsHardwareService>();
       Bind<IStatusApi>().To<StatusApiController>();
    }
}
```

But I am currently getting the following:

> Error activating IHardwareService
>
> No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
>   Activation path:
>
> 2) Injection of dependency IHardwareService into parameter service of constructor of type DashboardController
>
> 1) Request for DashboardController
>
> Suggestions:
>
> 1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for IHardwareService.
>
> 2) If the binding was defined in a module, ensure that the module has been loaded into the kernel.
>
> 3) Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel.
>
> 4) If you are using constructor arguments, ensure that the parameter name matches the constructors parameter name.
>
> 5) If you are using automatic module loading, ensure the search path and filters are correct.

Comment: Please [see the following answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31029859/894792).  I think it hits on similar points and will help you :).

Comment: @Coulton Thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't really answer, I don't want to use Property Injection, I was to be able to use Ninject MVC with other class library's, That may include moving my Bindings to somewhere more 'common'.

Comment: Ok no problem.  What kind of injection do you want to do if it's not property or constructor injection?

Comment: Is the question is about how to create ninject modules for your own registrations and where to put and reference them from?

Comment: @kayess Yes, I don't want my UI project referencing everything because I need to add the bindings in there, I need a 'common' project that has references to Ninject to be able to use it everywhere in the solution, while keeping the Ninject MVC part working.

Comment: Look at Ninject modules.  You need a NinjectModule that you can call for each of your separate projects that sets up the bindings that are specific to each of your projects.

Comment: Not sure that it's what you need, but still. In our project we create an `MvcApplication : NinjectHttpApplication` in Global.asax, create the Ninject Kernel in overridden `CreateKernel` method. If we want to resolve a class in a conroller not via constructor injection (which we never do though), we can do it via `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService` method. Plus in case you have to create and resolve objects in runtime, think about using `Ninject.Extensions.Factory`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't understand the question correctly at all(

Comment: @AndreySarafanov I updated to include what I have tried. It might be easier to see then.

Comment: If you follow the [example](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Modules-and-the-Kernel) the `GetKernel` method should look like this: `return new StandardKernel(new CoreModule());`. Not sure if it'll help but worth a try

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems that you have a lot of questions what needs to be answered here, so I will try to do my best.

Based on your current question I will try to "draw up" a simplified architecture of your current implementation:

- **Domain layer:** The core of your domain, place of your business entities, etc.
- **Infrastructure layer:** This is where your services reside e.g.: `WindowsHardwareService`

  - **IOC**: I tend to call to this as `DependencyResolution` assembly.
- **UI:** MVC application

Assuming this all above, we can state that your applications [`Composition Root`](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) or `Entry point` is the **UI** MVC project. One of the main concepts using a `DI Container` that is you initalize it in the `Composition Root` set up/do all your needed bindings and registrations here. The main intention to do it in the entry point is to avoid the [`Service Locator`](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) anti-pattern.

By using a `DI Container` you don't `new()` up your class implementations or get the kernel but rather ask for the registered dependency, following the rule of [`Inversion Of Control`](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/InversionOfControl.html) or also known as the Hollywood principle.

After the philosphy course, we can finally get to some actual implementation.

**Creating an [Ninject module](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Modules-and-the-Kernel):** in your **IOC** assembly, lets call this file as `ServiceModule.cs`

```
using Ninject.Modules;
public class ServiceModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IHardwareService>().To<WindowsHardwareService>();
        Bind<IStatusApi>().To<StatusApiController>();
    }
}
```

This will be the `Ninject module` that you will register/load in the `Composition Root`.

**Now about the Composition Root:** in **UI** MVC projects `NinjectWebCommon.cs`
You can have a method that is responsible loading your modules as below.

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    var modules = new List<INinjectModule>
        {
            new ServiceModule()
            //, new FooModule()
            //, new BarModule()
        };

    kernel.Load(modules);
}
```

**And finally your `DashboardController` in *UI* MVC:**

```
public class DashboardController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHardwareService _hardwareService;

    public DashboardController(IHardwareService hardwareService)
    {
        _hardwareService = hardwareService;
    }
}
```

At this point, your ask for the registered implementation of `IHardwareService` in the controllers constructor. The `DI Container` will do the dirty job and pass you the instance that you can work with later in your controller.

A note about the **interfaces**: I tend to put these into an own assembly, where I just store the interfaces, e.g.: `Project.Domain.Interfaces` or `Project.Infrastructure.Interfaces` where each of these assemblies contain only domain or infrastructure interfaces.

**References between assemblies:**

To put all these together the **UI** only references the **IOC** assembly and the **interfaces** assembly that containts the interfaces you bound in your `Ninject Module`.

**Summarizing all of the above:**

Your classes and interfaces alone by theirselves are just pieces what are getting *glued* together by the DI container.

Hope I cleared it up a bit.

**EDIT:** as some good advice that **@AndreySarafanov** pointed out in comments, if you need different implementations of an interface you ask for in the constructor, you can use a [Ninject Factory](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki). For more information you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285946/ioc-ninject-and-factories) answer.

Comment: Yes that makes a lot of sense, but I have the problem that for example I do not want the UI to reference the Infrastructure layer for SOC. I was attempting to create the IOC project to have all the references there and the UI will just reference the IOC project.

Comment: Excellent, but how can I access the Kernel in other projects? to do Kernel.Get<T> ?. Thinking about it, if everything is abstracted behind an interface and constructor injection is used, I should never need to `kernel.Get<T>` right?

Comment: Yes, exactly! You try and never do kernel.Get<>, you compose your object graph in the Compostion Root!

Comment: I'll just add that in cases when you need to create objects in runtime, it's better to add factories as dependencies, so that you won't need `Kernel.Get`. In simple cases those factories can be autoimplemented (e.g. via Ninject.Extensions.Factory).